# Search for a comma and remove if orphan

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a script that acts as a filter to remove elements from a page based on what the user types in, the filtering works great, when a user types a keyword it is added to a list,

a users input my look like this,

> look, ma, these, are, keywords, boom

and and the output of which you be,

- look
- ma
- these
- are
- keywords

on clicking on one of the list items I remove it from the list and also from the user input, my problem is those detecting whether as well as the keyword, I also need to remove a comma that is after the word. is there a way I can search to see if I need to remove a comma as well, my current script looks like this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-tag", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().animate({
            "width" : "0px",
            "overflow" : "hidden"
        }, 500, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            var str = $("#options_1").val();
            console.log(str);
            var newStr = str.replace($(this).text(), "");
            console.log(newStr);
            $("#options_1").val("");
            $("#options_1").val(newStr);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net or atleast post the HTML code?

Comment: I think you started it wrong... using javascript split and join method may be a better idea from where I see it

Comment: "Boom" is not listed? Typo or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a split and filtering, no regex:

```
var newStr = str.split(',').filter(function(n){return n.trim()}).join(',');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nB2TT/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regex `,?` which would optionally match `,`

```
var newStr = str.replace("\s*"+$(this).text()+"\s*,?", "");
```

`\s` matches a `space`..

`*` is a quantifier that matches preceeding character 0 to many times..so `\s*` means match 0 to many space